# Excel formula which returns the parent version for a given version string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have the following data within column A:

```
A1 = 3.5.15
A2 = 2.6
A3 = 8.4.3.16.7
```

I'd like to have a formula which can return the following in the next column B:

```
B1 = 3.5
B2 = 2
B3 = 8.4.3.16
```

I've looked into various string manipulation options with TRIM, LEFT, RIGHT, SEARCH, FIND, etc. , but I can't figure out a solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you want is:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))))-1)
```

[image]